# How to get value from dynamic object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGrid bind to a dynamic list, now what I want is to get value of selected item back from the DataGrid, but getting error `Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Receipt_Date'`

Below is the code:

```
 var selectedItem = itemsDataGrid.SelectedItem as dynamic;
 Debug.WriteLine(selectedItem.Receipt_Date); //This line is throwing exception.
```

When I print `selectedItem` in Immediate Window inside Visual Studio, I can see the values as below:

```
{ ID = 426, 
  Receipt_Date = 12/30/2014 12:00:00 AM, 
  Total= 380.8200, 
  Tax = 0.0000, 
  Amount_Final = 373.2000, 
  flag = 0.0000 }
```

I am new to dynamic and don't know where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: Why are you using a dynamic list? What types are you adding to it?

Comment: I have a complex EF join query to fetch values from database, so for that I have a function that is returning dynamic list.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: it might not answer the question, but the correct solution is to stop using `dynamic` and instead create a class for the query result. there is no reason at all not to. you are not saving coding speed, LoC or maintainability wrestling with `dynamic` when all you want is a simple databinding to a POCO

Comment: @kai you are right, but I have multiple result sets depends on user preferences, so creating POCO for all individual result set would be hard to maintain later.

Comment: @dotctor I have mentioned that in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Well I am going to start by pointing out the problems with your code...

```
var selectedItem = itemsDataGrid.SelectedItem as dynamic;
```

The use of `var` means that the compiler will infer a type by looking at assignments in code.  The issue is you've assigned `dynamic` to it and `dynamic` types are not bound until runtime.  So you have a contradiction in your code, you can't infer a type for the `var` when using a `dynamic`.  The compiler will verify every property or function call on a `var` type because it is expected to be a known type at compile time.  Dynamic does not work like that, properties and functions of a dynamic type are not verified at compile time.

You should try this:

```
dynamic d = itemsDataGrid.SelectedItem;
Debug.WriteLine(d.Receipt_Date);
```

Now my question to you is other than pure learning, why are you doing this?

I personally only use `dynamic` when accessing COM objects where I don't have a C# type available to me.

Comment: It is still throwing exception.
Reason to use dynamic:  
I have a complex EF join query to fetch values from database, so for that I have a function that is returning dynamic list